# Why notetitle & noteContent values are not being updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';

function ViewNoteComponent({ route }) {
    const { noteid } = useParams();
    const [noteTitle, setNoteTitle] = useState('');
    const [noteContent, setNoteContent] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/list-single?token=${token}&note_id=${noteid}`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Failed to fetch notes');
                }
            })
            .then((data) => {
                setNoteTitle(data.data[0].title);
                setNoteContent(data.data[0].content);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error.message));


    }, [noteid]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("checking...")

            handleSave();

        }, 3000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
            handleSave();
        };
    }, []);

    const handleSave = () => {
        console.log("saving...")
        console.log(noteTitle.length)
        if (noteTitle.length > 0 && noteContent.length > 0) {
            let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            let data = qs.stringify({ title: noteTitle, content: noteContent, token, note_id: noteid });

            console.log(data + 'sending');

            let config = {
                method: 'post',
                maxBodyLength: Infinity,
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/edit',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: data
            };

            axios
                .request(config)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    };

    const handleTitleChange = (event) => {
        console.log("title changing");
        const newTitle = event.target.value;
        setNoteTitle(newTitle);
        console.log(newTitle);
    };

    const handleContentChange = (event) => {
        console.log("content changing");
        const newContent = event.target.value;
        setNoteContent(newContent);
    };


    return (
        <>
            <div className='edit-area'>
                <input
                    className='input-note-title'
                    type='text'
                    onChange={handleTitleChange}
                    placeholder='Note title...'
                    value={noteTitle}
                />
                <textarea
                    className='input-note-content'
                    onChange={handleContentChange}
                    placeholder='Write something....'
                    value={noteContent}
                ></textarea>

                <button className='btn' >
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default ViewNoteComponent;
```

I want to have a interval which runs every 3 sec and saves the title and content . and the interval runs. but handlesave method is not saving the dta because length of these two variables are always 0. Why? Itried a temp variable too but that too does not give me solution. Please anyone here help me

Answer (score 0):

As per the hooks concept, you will need to **specify the dependency in the array of second argument** in useEffect.

In your code you are **calling the handleSave in useEffect without any dependency**, which means this will use the initial version of handleSave function with blank values of the states.

**Try below changes**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("checking...")
        handleSave();
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
        handleSave();
    };
}, [handleSave]);
```

Basically, this will update the handleSave function context with the latest values.